# Unable to use wagtail with multiple databases

Tags: python, django, wagtail

As the title suggests, I'm finding it difficult to use multiple databases with Wagtail.

My Objective is simple: Implementation of a scenario where all the `Django` as well as `Wagtail` tables will be created in the sqlite database for now rather than in the postgreSQL db.

The Why: Cause I'd like the postgreSQL DB to remain uncluttered as well as utilise it for search/select purposes using the `inspectdb` command.

The Error generated:

> relation "wagtailcore_page" does not exist

Cause for concern: In the default wagtail `home` app, `migrations` folder, there's a file: `0002_create_homepage.py` whose contents look like:

```
from django.db import migrations


def create_homepage(apps, schema_editor):
    # Get models
    ContentType = apps.get_model('contenttypes.ContentType')
    Page = apps.get_model('wagtailcore.Page')
    Site = apps.get_model('wagtailcore.Site')
```

So makes me wonder: is this an error that happens because Wagtail already has its own initial migration in the `home` app or am I doing something wrong? Better yet, how would I implement this concept with wagtail.

Here's my code:

#### base.py- database section

```
DATABASES = {
    'sqlite': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'options': '-c search_path=test_schema,public'
                },
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DBWORKNAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DBWORKUSER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DBWORKPASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DBWORKHOST'),
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = [
    'school.router.NonPersonalDBAttributeRouter'     # Router's module path
]
```

#### my_project_dir/router.py

```
class NonPersonalDBAttributeRouter:
    """
       Connects the app to the preferred database
    """
    non_personal_db_attribute_tables = [
                                    'auth', 'admin', 'contenttypes', 'sessions', 'messages', 'staticfiles', 'migrations',
                                    'wagtailadmin', 'wagtailcore', 'wagtaildocs', 'wagtailembeds', 'wagtailforms',
                                    'wagtailimages', 'wagtailredirects', 'wagtailsearch', 'wagtailusers'
                                      ]

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.non_miner_dev_attribute_tables:
            return 'sqlite'
        return None  # returns the External db

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        if model._meta.app_label in self.non_miner_dev_attribute_tables:
            return 'sqlite'
        return None  # returns the External db

    def allow_relation(self, obj1, obj2, **hints):
        if obj1._meta.app_label in self.non_miner_dev_attribute_tables or obj2._meta.app_label in self.non_miner_dev_attribute_tables:
            return True
        return None

    def allow_migrate(self, db, app_label, model_name=None, **hints):
        if app_label in self.non_miner_dev_attribute_tables:
            return db == 'sqlite'
        return None
```

The problem comes in when I run the initial migration. The Error:

#### makemigrations

```
Process finished with exit code 0
manage.py@school_src > makemigrations
Tracking file by folder pattern:  migrations
No changes detected

Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### migrate

```
manage.py@stuff_src > migrate
"C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\bin\runnerw.exe" C:\baronprojects\pythonprojects\djangoprojects\school_management_project\school_src\my_venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py" migrate C:/baronprojects/pythonprojects/djangoprojects/school_management_project/school_src
Tracking file by folder pattern:  migrations
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, home, sessions, taggit, wagtailadmin, wagtailcore, wagtaildocs, wagtailembeds, wagtailforms, wagtailimages, wagtailredirects, wagtailsearch, wagtailusers
Running migrations:
  Applying home.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "wagtailcore_page" does not exist


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 52, in <module>
    run_command()
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.1.4\helpers\pycharm\django_manage.py", line 46, in run_command
    run_module(manage_file, None, '__main__', True)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 205, in run_module
    return _run_module_code(code, init_globals, run_name, mod_spec)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 96, in _run_module_code
    mod_name, mod_spec, pkg_name, script_name)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:/baronprojects/pythonprojects/djangoprojects/school_management_project/school_src\manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py", line 247, in apply_migration
    migration_recorded = True
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 110, in __exit__
    self.execute(sql)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py", line 137, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Python36\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "wagtailcore_page" does not exist
```

Comment: Why don't you make sqlite the default db? Since your want postgres database not to be managed by Django (Model.Meta.managed=False). Seems logical to make Postgres database the 'other' option.

Comment: Did that. Problem is: sqlite does work in that sense except `inspectdb` which is the aim of this whole thing seems to only work on the `default` database(in this case, postgresql).   Hence why I'm conflicted on finding out why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was able to sort it out by using sqlite as the default.
I then used the command `inspectdb` followed by the name of the database, i.e: `postgres` as per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-inspectdb-database)
thereby achieving my objective: Keeping the external DB clean.

Here's the Code:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    },
    'postgres': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'OPTIONS': {
                    'options': '-c search_path=test_schema,public'
                },
        'NAME': os.environ.get('DBWORKNAME'),
        'USER': os.environ.get('DBWORKUSER'),
        'PASSWORD': os.environ.get('DBWORKPASSWORD'),
        'HOST': os.environ.get('DBWORKHOST'),
    }
}
```

Command used:

```
manage.py@reverse_src > inspectdb --database postgres
Tracking file by folder pattern:  migrations
# This is an auto-generated Django model module.
# You'll have to do the following manually to clean this up:
#   * Rearrange models' order
#   * Make sure each model has one field with primary_key=True
#   * Make sure each ForeignKey has `on_delete` set to the desired behavior.
#   * Remove `managed = False` lines if you wish to allow Django to create, modify, and delete the table
# Feel free to rename the models, but don't rename db_table values or field names.
from django.db import models


class DjangoMigrations(models.Model):
    app = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    applied = models.DateTimeField()

class TblCountry(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=-1, blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_country'
```

- NB, `TblCountry` was just a test table I created within postgresql to see whether it would work. Also notice, there was no need for the router.py file as well as its configuration